# HTTPD with SSL startup fails with missing PAM library error

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, pam, rhel7

I am configuring SSL to run with Apache 2.4 on RHEL7. As expected, httpd starts successfully before SSL configuration is added. After adding certificates and configuration files, startup fails with the message "PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_lsass.so)". I have not been able to find any documentation concerning the relationship between PAM and SSL.
My config files are:

```
SSL CONFIGURATION FILE
```

```
Listen 443 https  
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/etc/httpd/conf.d/getpass  
<VirtualHost XXX.121.XXX.85:443>  
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log  
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log  
    LogLevel debug  
    SSLEngine on  
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3  
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:+MEDIUM:!SSLv2:!EXP:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL  
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/tsl.crt  
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/tsl.key  
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/GE_bundle.cer  
    SSLVerifyClient  
</VirtualHost>
```

```
HTTPD CONFIGURATION FILE
```

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"  
Timeout 60  
Listen XXX.121.XXX.85:80  
Header set X-Frame-Options "deny"  
Include conf.d/*.conf  
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE  
User apache  
Group apache  
ServerSignature Off  
FileETag None  
TraceEnable Off  
ServerAdmin t@example.com  
ServerName ms.example.com:80  
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none  
    Require all denied
</Directory>  
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"  
<Directory "/var/www">  
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride None  
    Require all granted
</Directory>  
<Directory "/var/www/html">  
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes  
    FileETag None 
    <LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>  
        Require all denied 
    </LimitExcept>  
    AllowOverride None  
    Require all granted  
</Directory> 
<Directory "/tsl">  
    Options +ExecCGI -Indexes -Includes  
    AllowOverride None  
    FileETag None 
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>  
       Require all granted
    </Limit> 
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>  
        Require all denied  
    </LimitExcept>  
</Directory>  
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/evm">  
    AllowOverride None  
    Options None  
    Require all granted  
    FileETag None  
</Directory>  
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/test">  
    AllowOverride None  
    FileETag None  
    Options None  
    Require all granted  
</Directory>  
<IfModule dir_module>  
    DirectoryIndex index.html  
</IfModule>  
<Files ".ht*">  
    Require all denied  
</Files>  
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"  
LogLevel debug  
<IfModule log_config_module>  
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined  
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common  
    <IfModule logio_module>  
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio  
    </IfModule>  
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined  
</IfModule>  
<IfModule alias_module>  
    Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"  
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"  
    ScriptAlias /utilities/ "/tsl/"  
</IfModule>  
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">  
    AllowOverride None  
    Options None  
    FileETag None  
    Require all granted  
</Directory>  
<IfModule mime_module>  
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types  
    AddType application/x-compress .Z  
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz  
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi  
    AddType text/html .shtml  
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml  
</IfModule>  
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8  
<IfModule mime_magic_module>  
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic  
</IfModule>  
EnableSendfile on
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the complete error messages.

Comment: Does /usr/lib64/security/pam_lsass.so exist and is it world-readable?